# Bundling .dll inside of .jar

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jfilechooser, filechooser

I'm using XFileDialog (https://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/) instead of JFileChooser, but I want to bundle the dll's inside the .jar so I don't have to ship them with the application.

So I added them to the project, but I'm not sure how to reference them. Inside XFileDialog.class I found `System.loadLibrary("xfiledialog64");`

I guess this has to be changed to `System.load("xfiledialog64")`.

Is this correct?

The other issue is that I am not able to edit the .class file from inside Eclipse. Does this mean that I have to edit the .class in the source and then re-compile it?

Answer (score 3):

Since it is apparently a desktop app., one strategy is to launch it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  If launched using web start, the natives would be loaded as they are normally loaded.

Here is the [JNLP used to load the applet demo.](https://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/downloads/detail?name=applet.jnlp&can=2&q=)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>helloapplet</title>
        <vendor>stevpan</vendor>
</information>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="win_x86_dll.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <nativelib href="win_x64_dll.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="hello.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>

    <applet-desc 
         name="helloapplet"
         main-class="helloapplet"
         width="640"
         height="480">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: It (singular)?  The above JNLP suggests you should start thinking about 'them' (plural).